# two ROS versions in the same time

Tags: ros-fuerte, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone
Is it possible for me to use two differnet ROS versions in my system in the same time? For example i have fuerte and i wuold like to have hydro too.
thanks:))

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189567/two-ros-versions-in-the-same-time/) by [mohammad](https://answers.ros.org/users/19955/mohammad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2014-08-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-09**:
Define "same time". Do you mean installed or running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to install multiple ROS versions, then you can find the answer at this link.
http://answers.ros.org/question/58221/how-i-manage-multiple-ros-distributions-groovy-electric-fuerte/

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See also http://answers.ros.org/question/187548/can-i-install-multiple-ros-version-on-the-same-machine/ about supported platforms

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-08-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1